# What is the 'head' in this song?

Tags: terminology, sheet-music, jazz, the-real-book

I'm using this music sheet from the New Real book 1 to play Grover Washington Jr's Make Me A Memory, and I'm trying to understand the structure of the song, as it is written at the bottom right corner:

[image]

But I'm not sure what follows the D.S. After the solo, I go to the `S` (9th measure) and play from there, but what is the *head* that I have to play? Is it the *A* ?

Comment: not sure if it is OK to post reproduction of copyrighted material here.

Comment: I have no idea what "kicks do not hold for solos" means either. Just when you think you know what you're doing, something totally new comes along.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I guess it's at B, where it has a specific rhythmic pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_%28music%29) being the main theme of the song, it is indeed the A part that has to be played. This can also be confirmed by listening to the [original recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZUnO6RCGqI).

Answer (score -1):

Head is intro + AABBAABB

"kicks do not hold for solos" means don't play the figures above the staff in the B section during the solos.